# Will I incur late fees, now that I am making infrequent/late payments on my auto loan?

Tags: united-states, loans, fees, penalty, auto-loan

I have been unemployed for 6 months now. I have been making *infrequent* payments on my auto loan. I am suppose to be paid up in May of 2012.  My lien holder never sends me my balances or a bill, so I don't know how much I owe at this point.

Since I am late often should I expect to pay late fees at the end of my loan?

Comment: Most lenders have online systems that let you look this sort of information up. You don't say who your lender is or where you are located, but you should check (Google?) to see if your lender has such a web-site.

Answer (score 3):

As the others said, contact the bank. The expression "lien holder" is right, but not really common in the US, where are you located? 
There are contract laws in any country that would require disclosure before any kind of loan is made. Your paperwork should spell out the late fee/interest/penalty, if any.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to contact your lender to figure out the existing balance as well as any penalties you may need to pay.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your loan paperwork first.  See where you stand.  I'd find out as much as you can without contacting them, just yet.

If you contact them to explain the situation, it's a bit like spinning a roulette wheel.  They could (a) work something out with you or (b) move to repossess.  If you've been making infrequent payments for a while, they may do this anyway.

Here's a discussion specific to Virginia:

http://www.debtconsolidationcare.com/forums/carrepo-va.html